# php while fgetcvs function - displaying only last x lines

Tags: php, file, get, lines

I have a code that works just fine:

```
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "|")) !== FALSE) {
   echo $data[0].$data[1].$data[2]."<br />\n";
   }
fclose($handle);
}
```

But it gets all the contents from file.csv and I want just last x lines.  I tried slice method and etc.  thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can't you load each line into an array instead of echoing it, and then process that?

Comment: @user2483110: Please correct the title of your question: csv instead of cvs.

Answer (score 0):

If the command line utility [`tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) is on your `PATH`, then you can use this snippet:

```php
$x = 3;
if (($handle = popen(sprintf("tail --lines=%d file.csv", $x), "rb")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        echo $data[0].$data[1].$data[2]."<br />\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

The PHP function `fgetcsv` will always parse one row at a time.